# SAS: Display SQL pushed down to the database

Tags: sas

As the title says, I'm very interested in knowing if there is a way to display/show the SQL that SAS actually pushes down to the database?

I know the general stuff, such as to avoid custom SAS functions in your proc sql, and use tables from the same library etc. But it would be very useful to see the SQL sent to the database as some functions might be supported while some are not.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

options sastrace=',,,d' sastraceloc=saslog nostsuffix;

That will show the SQL statements that are pushed down in the SAS log.